# How to show no matched record found match when we use default filter in angularjs ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How to show no matched record found match when we use default filter in angularjs ui grid;
Current when we use filter and data does not contain that value the blank screen is appearing

Comment: Do you mean show a message that no matches were found?

Comment: Yes sir i want to show no record found

Comment: Check out the answer I posted, let me know if it is what you aimed for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which filtering you use.

**Server-side filtering:**

Just check rows length:

```
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions">
    <div ng-if="grid.rows.length === 0" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; right: 0; text-align: center;">No data.</div>
  </div>
```

This works also if initial data are empty or filters filter them out.

**Client-side filtering:**

Rows are always there, just their visibility matters as they get filtered out.

Then you need to add some getter to controller to check whether there are visible rows, like this:

```
vm.hasVisibleRows = function() {
  return vm.gridApi.grid.rows.filter(function(e) { return e.visible; }).length > 0;
}
```

and use this one in view:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" class="grid">
  <div ng-if="!$ctrl.hasVisibleRows()" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; right: 0; text-align: center;">No data.</div>
</div>
```

You can style the message appearance any way you want then.

Comment: This will add the 'No Data' <div> underneath the grid and not inside it, which is what I understand the question is asking for, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I tried to use this suggestion and maybe I'm doing wrong but it did not work for me - I used the plunker provided in the ui-grid filtering tutorial (ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20103%20Filtering) and edited it with your suggested answer here: next.plnkr.co/edit/2ogd8mhQyUfqqPIM but when typing 'zzz' in the filter box all the lines were hidden but the 'No Data' message was not displayed. I think the ng-if checks grid.rows but it is not accessible. I tried $scope.gridOptions.rows and $scope.gridOptions.data but no luck either

Comment: @ArielGro: you're right, I updated my answer. I meant he uses server-side filtering, in that case rows are not there - so my original answer applies. In case he uses client side filtering (like you in your plunkr), rows I always there, just their visibility changes. See http://next.plnkr.co/edit/2xmiakk2ds6CJI5Y for client-side filtering solution.

Comment: I see what you did..
And looks like it works, I just hate using absolute position :)

Comment: Although I hate using 'position:absolute', you get my up-vote for showing both external and internal filtering..

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is using external filtering and using the filter function to detect when there is no data left after filtering. You can use it to change a flag on the $scope and use that flag to switch a div with a message on or off for example.

Here is the link on external filtering - http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20308%20External%20Filtering

I took the plunker they have there and edited it to demonstrate my solution suggestion.
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Afzv98kxxyMObK9r

Check the `filterChanged` function and notice what I did with the `allData` field to save the full data when filtering.